# React: missing dependency warning within interval in effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-effect

I have a react page built with *React* and *Next.js* that looks like this.

```js
import Head from 'next/head';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header';

export default function Home() {
    const ticksPerSecond = 10;

    const [points, setPoints] = useState(10);
    const [pointsPerSecond, setPointsPerSecond] = useState(2);

    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            setPoints((points) => points + pointsPerSecond / ticksPerSecond);
        }, 1000 / ticksPerSecond);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <Header points={points} pointsPerSecond={pointsPerSecond} />
        </>
    );
}
```

This code works as intended. Every second, `points` will increase by `pointsPerSecond`, and the state will be updated 10 times a second (as determined by `ticksPerSecond`).

My issue comes from *eslint* which warns me:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'pointsPerSecond'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also replace multiple useState variables with useReducer if 'setPoints' needs the current value of 'pointsPerSecond'.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Having read that warning, I have tried many different solutions to appease the eslint gods in the sky, but the best I can do it replace the warnings with different warnings. Specifically, I have tried the solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook) which looks like the same problem. However, none of those solutions suppress the warning.

Comment: Is `pointsPerSecond` going to potentially change at some point? Why is it stateful?

Comment: @Nick Yes it will be changed as part of usage in the application. It hasn't been implemented yet

Comment: And is `ticksPerSecond` never going to change?

Comment: @Nick ticksPerSecond is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend adding `pointsPerSecond` to the dependency array and then making sure to return a *cleanup function* from your effect to clear the existing interval. This assumes you want to stop any existing interval and start a new one whenever `pointsPerSecond` changes. If you don't include `pointsPerSecond` in the dependency array, you'll be working with a stale version of that dependency.

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header';

const ticksPerSecond = 10;

export default function Home() {
    const [points, setPoints] = useState(10);
    const [pointsPerSecond, setPointsPerSecond] = useState(2);

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setPoints((points) => points + pointsPerSecond / ticksPerSecond);
        }, 1000 / ticksPerSecond);

        return () => { clearInterval(interval) }
    }, [pointsPerSecond]);

    return (
        <>
            <Header points={points} pointsPerSecond={pointsPerSecond} />
        </>
    );
}
```

There are a couple reasons I almost always recommend against silencing linting errors for hook dependency arrays:

- It's almost always the case that you want your hook to have the most current value.
- If you silence the lint warnings for the dependency array, then you won't get these warnings for *future* dependencies for which you might really want to have the warnings.

Comment: Because pointsPerSecond can change, wouldn't this cause two intervals to run at once?

Comment: No. The cleanup function returned from the `useEffect` hook clears the previous interval

Answer (score 0):

A couple of changes I would do.

1. Don't forget to clearInterval on unmouted,
2. Do a mounted check before calling setState's.
3. Add the dependancy esLint is warning you about.

Below is an example.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let mounted = true;
  const i = setInterval(() => {
    if (mounted) setPoints((points) => points + pointsPerSecond / ticksPerSecond);
  }, 1000 / ticksPerSecond);
  return () => { clearInterval(i); mounted = false; }
}, [pointsPerSecond]);
```

Comment: This is interesting, what does the `mounted` variable offer that clearing the interval doesn't?

Comment: Because pointsPerSecond can change, wouldn't this cause two intervals to run at once?

Comment: @JulianLachniet  No, that's why we do clearInterval.

Comment: @Nick  It's just in case the interval still fires after un-mounting, it generally doesn't cause issues, apart from getting warnings in the console from React about calling setState on an un-mounted component.  For something trivial like this it's maybe not an issue, but any form of async code I now just do a mounted check anyway, I just don't like console clutter. :).

Answer (score -1):

Try adding pointsPerSecond on dependency array

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setPoints((points) => points + pointsPerSecond / ticksPerSecond);
    }, 1000 / ticksPerSecond);
  }, [pointsPerSecond]);
```

Or you can just ignore the warning using
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setPoints((points) => points + pointsPerSecond / ticksPerSecond);
    }, 1000 / ticksPerSecond);
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this start another interval whenever pointsPerSecond changed?

Comment: in this case you can use   // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
to disable the warning